# Scroll Issues on iPhone 5s on Chrome and Safari

Tags: amp-html

We have integrated Accelerated Mobile Pages by Google on our website. However, the scroll is getting stuck either at the top or at the bottom when the page is being viewed on iPhone 5s. This issue is happening on both Safari and Chrome browsers. Below is one of the links with this issue:
http://www.tabletwise.com/5-mono-tablet-10mg-biochem-pharma/side-effects/amp

Any help resolving this issue will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There may be several issues affecting this page. You can see them here:

```
http://www.tabletwise.com/5-mono-tablet-10mg-biochem-pharma/side-effects/amp#development=1
```

I don't believe that Google currently acknowledges `"@type": "MedicalWebPage"`; I believe that only `NewsArticle` and `Blog` currently are acknowledged.

You may wish to reconsider these dimensions:

```
header._mobile .search_input {font-size: 14px;width: calc(100% - 70px);}
header._mobile .search_button {width: 70px;font-size: 14px;}
```

The [W3C CSS validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator) reports errors on those dimensions.